# How to select all records with non repeated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table

```
ID - NAME
1-John  
1-John 
2-Saly
3-Saly
4-Oman
```

I need a result to look like:

```
name | count
John    1
Saly   2
Oman   1
```

Consider the duplicated ID and name as 1 record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select NAME, count(distinct ID) as COUNT
from T1
group by NAME
```

Here's a complete test script:

```
create table T1 (id int, name varchar(20))

insert T1 values (1, 'John')
insert T1 values (1, 'John')
insert T1 values (2, 'Saly')
insert T1 values (3, 'Saly')
insert T1 values (4, 'Oman')


select NAME, count(distinct ID) as COUNT
from T1
group by NAME
```